# Send String from an Activity to a Fragment of another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two Activities (A and B) and a Fragment F
The Fragment F is contained in the Activity B
I'd like to send Strings from Activity A to Fragment F
How can do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you'll actually send that string to your activity B. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityClass.class);
intent.putExtra("myString", "this is your string");
startActivity(intent);
```

then later read that string from your activity B and inject into your fragment before executing the fragment-transaction. For example:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("myString", getIntent().getExtras().getString("myString"))
yourFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Later, use `getArguments()` in your fragment to retrieve that bundle.

---

Or alternatively, use the following in your fragment to directly access the activity intent and fetch your required value:

```
String str = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("myString");
```

For more info, read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: @Santhosh answer is simpler.

Answer (score 9):

It is Almost same as you would exchange data between activities. you should just use getActivity() in the beginning in order to access in fragments.

check below code:

> **In Activity A:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("data",data); //data is a string variable holding some value.
startActivity(intent);
```

> **In fragment F of Activity B**

```
String data = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment.java file add the following code,

```
public static String name= null;

public void setName(String string){
name = string;
}
```

In MainActivity.java from which you want to send String add the following code,

```
String stringYouWantToSend;

Fragment fragment =  new Fragment();
fragment.setName(stringYouWantToSend);
```