# How do I pass a string from inside a loop in a function in one class to another class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to pass a string catcode (which is the selected category in the respective categories) which is defined in 2 loops in one of my functions in class1 to another class2 , but not sure how to go about it. Any clue? 
Here's my code:
In Class1:

```
public void onClick(final View view) {
switch (view.getId()) {
...cases..
case R.id.button_done:
...case stuff...
Intent intent = new Intent();

                if(abcNews != null && abcNews.size() > 0){
                    for(CategoryCheckableRow rwa : abcNews){
                        if(rwa.isSelected()){

                            String catCode = rwa.getCategoryName();
                            intent.putExtra("cat_name", catCode);
                            Log.d("newsdash", "category name is"+catCode);

                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                if(cnnNews != null && cnnNews.size() > 0){
                    for(CategoryCheckableRow rwa : cnnNews){
                        if(rwa.isSelected()){

                            String catCode = rwa.getCategoryName();
                            intent.putExtra("cat_name", catCode);

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

As seen in this code, In these 2 loops I have defined catCode, which I need to pass on to class 2 such that:
Class2:

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    frontpageHeader = view.findViewById(R.id.frontpage_header);
            ((TextView) frontpageHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(getActivity().getString(catCode));
            frontpageHeader.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

P.S: Please note I am uusing only one category at a time ,say either the catCode in abnews is selected OR cnnNews is selected and that string is recognized and needs to be passed on to another class class2 where it updates the header based on selected text.

Comment: I think you are talking two Activity classes class1 and class2.What happens at the time of the above code execution.Does the header TextView shows the value from the class1?.Else if there any error please show the logcat.Does the Activity class2 shows up.?

Comment: the current class 2 is a static string, trying to make it dynamic so it can pick up values from class1 for the category selected

Answer (score 0):

You are already puting catCode in your intent, but I think your problem is your Class2 is a fragment and not an activity, so asuming you are creating your fragment in code you have to put something like this in the activity you are starting

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
fragment.setArguments(extras);
```

And in your fragment

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String catCode = bundle.getString("cat_name");
```

Comment: I tried this instead : if(abcNews != null && abcNews.size() > 0){
   for(CategoryCheckableRow rwa : abcNews){
    if(rwa.isSelected()){
     String catCode = rwa.getCategoryName();
     intent.putExtra("cat_name", catCode);
    
  ((TextView) frontpageHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(getActivity().getString(catCode));
   } but it shows error on catcode for getstring. is there a way to define it?

Comment: getActivity().getString‌​(catCode) Shows an error because it is trying to find "catCode" in your resources not the one you used in your intent

Comment: ok I tried   ((TextView) frontpageHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(catCode);
but that caused a crash. I have a MainActivity in which i have the base code : String catName = data.getStringExtra("cat_name");
   DashboardFragment f = DashboardFragment.getInstance();
   if(f != null){
    DashboardFrontPageFragment fpFrg = f.getFrontPage();
    fpFrg.setkeyword(catName);
    fpFrg.restartLoader();
   }//closing of first if

Comment: i m not sure how to use that, do i use the first block in the main activity where i defined the other code and second in createview of the other place? how do i make a change to my code based on your suggestion

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212469/send-string-from-an-activity-to-a-fragment-of-another-activity

Comment: Yes,This will definitely outs an error.((TextView) frontpageHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(catCode);.When R.id.header_title (ie,the header textview) is not used or not presented in the acitivity(THat means the parent of header textview is another Activity or Fragment that the above code executes.